# CSS: trigger hover of every <div> in an <a> tag

Tags: css

I'm trying to trigger the hover state on 2 div in a link.
Please consider the following code :

```css
.social-container {
    list-style: none;
}
.social-container>li>a {
    color: blue;
}
.social-container>li>a:hover {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.social-link {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.icon {
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.icon-linkedin {
        background-color: green;
}
.icon-linkedin:hover, .icon-linkedin.hovered {
        background-color: yellow;
}
.icon-github {
        background-color: black;
}
.icon-github:hover, .icon-github.hovered {
        background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="social-container">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="social-link">
        <div class="icon icon-linkedin social-li"></div>
        <div>linkedin.com</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="social-link">
        <div class="icon icon-github social-li"></div>
        <div>github.com</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do to trigger every div inside my link when hovering any of them ?
It works fine when I hover the icon but not when I hover the text.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Incidentally, how is the `.hovered` class applied? With JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, I realize that I first tried to do it with JavaScript but it was a mistake and I didn't remove it

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I ask because I didn't include that class in my answer. I wasn't sure which element it would be applied to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest defining `:hover` states on the parent `<a>` elements rather than the child `<div>` elements.

I've changed these:

```
.icon-linkedin:hover
.icon-github:hover
```

To these:

```
.social-link:hover .icon-linkedin
.social-link:hover .icon-github
```

Functional example:

```css
.social-container {
  list-style: none;
}
.social-link {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: blue;
}
.icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon-linkedin {
  background-color: green;
}
.icon-github {
  background-color: black;
}

.social-link:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.social-link:hover .icon-linkedin {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.social-link:hover .icon-github {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="social-container">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="social-link">
        <div class="icon icon-linkedin social-li"></div>
        <div>linkedin.com</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="social-link">
        <div class="icon icon-github social-li"></div>
        <div>github.com</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine ! Thanks for your fast answer